# how to track or detect the formatting of a USB device and how to know it is completed formatting using c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, usb

I want to create a user privileged EXE that can detect the formmating of USB device, and inform that the device is started formatting and when it completed it shows a message formatting is completed.

Created a C++ console application with the below example code.
But it needs admin privilege.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
   {
char *Fpath="D:\\$Extend\\$RmMetadata\\$TxfLog\\$TxfLog.blf";
std::ifstream is;
while(true)
{
    is.open(Fpath);
    if(is.is_open())
    {
        std::cout<<"Waiting for format\n";
        is.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"formating device\n";
    }
    Sleep(1000);
}
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I got the answer


#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    while(true)
    {
        WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
        HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(L"D:\\*.*",&data); // specify the drive letter

        if( h!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) 
        {
            cout << "Waiting\n";
        } 
        else 
            cout << "Formatting\n";
        FindClose(h);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this process needs admin privileges, it needs it, there is no option. You may set NTFS permissions (I'm not sure how to do for USB physical file), or you need to set Local Security Policy (again not sure which one - open with `secpol.msc`). But I asssume you cannot do much about it.

To make your process have higher privileges (elevated privilege), you need to set linker option:

[image]

Comment: there is any other solutions for it, without using the **admin privileges**?

Comment: May be. From where you got the idea of `D:\\$Extend\\$RmMetadata..` ?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-system-process-locking-external-hdd/76170b41-c5e5-4cad-a20e-793d2a8b2b16 

while formatting a drive this file will be removed and automatically generates after it.